# Show that direct sum of a representation with its complex conjugate is defined over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, representation-theory, direct-sum

If I have a matrix representation $\phi$: $G → GL(d, \mathbb{C})$ and make a direct sum with its complex conjugate, how do I prove that this sum is matrix representation of G over $\mathbb{R}$?
I would perhaps prove equivalence with some real matrix representation $\psi$: $\phi$: $G → GL(2d, \mathbb{R})$, but just don´t know the steps.

Comment: There is a natural embedding ${\rm GL}(d,{\mathbb C}) \to {\rm GL}(2d,{\mathbb R})$. Compose $\phi$ with this embedding and show  (by considering their characters) that the resulting representation is equivalent to the sum of $\phi$ with its complex conjugate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac 12 
\pmatrix{I & iI\\-iI & -I}
\pmatrix{A + iB & 0\\0 & A - iB}
\pmatrix{I & iI\\-iI & -I}
= \pmatrix{A & -B\\B & A}.
$$